# Pandas stack output formatting post pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a pivot table from the data frame by giving 2 columns as pivot input as shown in the code below. After applying pivot I need to use this stacked output to merge with a similar column data frame, for that I want to discard the name('Brand & type') which is also appearing above the index name, how can I achieve this. please note I want to keep stacked output

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'day':['aug','aug','sep','sep','aug'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Hyundai Elite i20'],
        'Type':['sedan,','sedan','hatchback','hatchback','hatchback'],
        'Down Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000,10000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['day','Brand', 'Type','Down Price'])
dfpivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day'],columns=['Brand','Type'],values=['Down Price'],aggfunc=np.max)
dfpivot.columns = dfpivot.columns.droplevel(0)
```

I tried to reset the index but it didn't work

```
dfpivot.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Then I tried to drop the index, which also didn't work. How can I remove Name Brand & Type which is appearing above the index. Thank you in advance.

after adding solution

```
dfpivot.columns.name=[None,None]
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-ef1eb88ee6b2> in <module>
     10 dfpivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day'],columns=['Brand','Type'],values=['Down Price'],aggfunc=np.max)
     11 
---> 12 dfpivot.columns.name=[None,None]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in name(self, value)
   1192                 "'MultiIndex.set_names' instead."
   1193             )
-> 1194         maybe_extract_name(value, None, type(self))
   1195         self._name = value
   1196 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in maybe_extract_name(name, obj, cls)
   5402     # GH#29069
   5403     if not is_hashable(name):
-> 5404         raise TypeError(f"{cls.__name__}.name must be a hashable type")
   5405 
   5406     return name

TypeError: MultiIndex.name must be a hashable type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the column `names`. Just set them to `None`:

```
dfpivot.columns.names = [None, None]
dfpivot.index.names = [None] # only do this if you do not want the name of your index (day)
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for such a prompt response. I have tried this after your suggestion, it throws this error-TypeError: MultiIndex.name must be a hashable type

Comment: Please add the full traceback to the questions.

Comment: added as requested

Comment: @DD08 Based on the traceback it looks like you used `name` singular and not `names` plural : `dfpivot.columns.name=[None,None]` it should be `dfpivot.columns.names = [None, None]`

Comment: It_is_Chris.  I did so minor mistake, Thank you for suggestion and pointing out mistake